# How to prevent CKEditor from replacing spaces with &nbsp;?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I'm using CKEditor 4.2 with D7 and the editor is replacing every space with an HTML non-breaking space. For instance, if I type: *This is a paragraph* and then either save or view source, I'll get the following:

```
<p>This&nbsp;is&nbsp;a&nbsp;paragraph.</p>
```

I don't have any HTML correctors/prettifiers running as filters and I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure out what's causing this.

Oh, I also have *Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities.* unchecked, so that's not it.

Has anyone seen this before? Any solutions out there?

Comment: As far as I know by default it does no such thing, so the question is - how did it started?

Comment: Great question. I have not added any plugins to the editor or changed the configuration significantly. I did tweak ckeditor.config.js to set the height, but that's it. This did just start happening, so I'll back that out, but I have a hard time believeing that's it.

Comment: Backed out my changes to no avail. This is frustrating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solve this with a [text filter](https://drupal.org/node/213156)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_filter_info().
 */
function MYMODULE_filter_info() {
  $filters = array();

  $filters['kill_nbsp'] = array(
    'title' => t('Kill Non-Breaking Spaces'),
    'description' => t('Remove non-breaking spaces.'),
    'process callback' => '_MYMODULE_filters_kill_nbsp',
    'tips callback' => '_MYMODULE_filters_kill_nbsp_tips',
  );

  return $filters;
}

/**
 * Filter callbacks.
 */
function _MYMODULE_filters_kill_nbsp($text, $filter) {
  return preg_replace('/&nbsp;/', ' ', $text);
}

/**
 * Filter tips.
 */
function _MYMODULE_filters_kill_nbsp_tips($filter, $format, $long = FALSE) {
  if (!$long) {
    // This string will be shown in the content add/edit form.
    return t('Don\'t use non-breaking spaces.  Ever.');
  }
  else {
    // And this one on the "Filter Tips" page.
    return t('Non-breaking spaces are evil and will be eradicated.');
  }
}
```

The code simply searches for non-breaking spaces and replaces them with normal spaces.

Stuff this in a custom module, and then assign the filter to the input formats that have WYSIWYG enabled.  This does assume that you never want actual non-breaking spaces in your output, which is good for my sites.

Comment: As it turns out, I had broken CKEditor trying to tweak its event model, so that was causing my spaces issue, but your answer works. Thank you.

Comment: Would this code work for Drupal 8?

Comment: @MrPaulDriver Copy/paste into Drupal 8, no.  Filters are now plugins, https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/filter-api/overview

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will remove leading white spaces for ckeditor

var val =  CKEDITOR.instances.[name_of_field].getData();//get data

val = $(val).text().trim();//remove white spaces